# Is it possible to import an excel table to a site and make it searchable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, search

Thank you in advance for any help.

So i have a table that has 100 rows and 4 columns. I want to publish it on to a site and make it searchable (filtering etc). Now i know one can use OneDrive to get a responsive table on excel itself but i am not allowed to use One drive for security Reasons. The way i have it setup right now i have to create the table in html in Dreamweaver then it is searchable using JavaScript. This is great for small tables but for large tables it takes forever to build the table in html i was wondering if there is a way to import an excel file to do this instead of building the table in html and make it searchable. I found the following thread that says how to do it i think but i am not full understanding it. I just want to know Is this something that is possible or am i wasting my time.

https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/save-excel-as-web-page-html-and-filter-table-how-to-achieve-this.31669/

Comment: 100 rows is not really a "large" table

Comment: yes you can please follow link https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3593-excel-convert-cells-to-html-table.html#a2

Comment: This is just one there are some with 10000+ rows. And converting it to html makes sense i am just struggling on the filter part. I want to be able to filter/search the table on the site. how do i go about doing that. Thank you